# strange thing about calloc

Tags: c, calloc

I was writing some code and I used the function `calloc`.

I understand that, when the first and the second arguments passed to this function are both zero, the function is going to alloc the necessary space for 0 elements, each of them with size 0, but here is the strange thing.

This program works fine even if n > 0. Why is that happening? I think it should display an error because I'm trying to write in a position of the array that doesn't exist. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int *test = calloc(0, 0);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    test[i] = 100;
    printf("%d ", test[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior means anything can happen.

Comment: no syntax errors = no compile errors in `c`. What you have compiles fine, but you are writing beyond your memory region (when `n > 0`) which is undefined behavior.

Comment: You don't get errors for things like this in c. It will just try and write it to the address specified. You as the programmer have to be careful to make sure it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, a lot of wrong and "wrong" things don't display error messages from the compiler. In fact, you may not even see error messagens when you run the program -- but another person running your program in a different computer may see the error.

One important concept in C is called *undefined behavior*. To put it in simple terms, it means that the behavior of your program is unpredictable, but you can read more about this subject in this question: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Your program is undefined for a two reasons:

1. When either `size` or `nmemb` is zero, `calloc()` may return `NULL`. Your program is not checking the output of `calloc()`, so there's a good chance that when you do `test[i]` you are attempting to derreference a `NULL` pointer -- you should always check the result of `calloc()` and `malloc()`.
2. When you call `malloc()` or `calloc()`, you are essentialy allocating dynamic memory for an array. You can use your pointer to access the elements of the array. But you can't access anything *past* the array. That is, if you allocate `n` elements you should not try to access the `n+1`-th element -- nether for reading.

Both items above make your program invoke undefined behavior. There **might** also be something undefined about accessing an empty object other than item #2 listed above, but I'm unsure.

You should always be careful about undefined behavior because, when your program invokes UB, it is essentialy **unpredictable**. You *could* see a compilation error, the program *could* give an error messagen, it *could* run successfuly without any problems or it *could* wipe out every single file in your hard disk.